# Authentication for a Flask API

Tags: python, authentication, web-services, flask

I've written a couple of functions to check if a consumer of the API should be authenticated to use it or not.

Have I done anything blatantly wrong here?

**Config**

```
API_CONSUMERS = [{'name': 'localhost',
                  'host': '12.0.0.1:5000',
                  'api_key': 'Ahth2ea5Ohngoop5'},
                 {'name': 'localhost2',
                  'host': '127.0.0.1:5001',
                  'api_key': 'Ahth2ea5Ohngoop6'}]
```

**Exceptions**

```
class BaseException(Exception):

    def __init__(self, logger, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseException, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        logger.info(self.message)


class UnknownHostException(BaseException):
    pass


class MissingHashException(BaseException):
    pass


class HashMismatchException(BaseException):
    pass
```

**Authentication methods**

```
import hashlib
from flask import request
from services.exceptions import (UnknownHostException, MissingHashException,
    HashMismatchException)


def is_authenticated(app):
    """
    Checks that the consumers host is valid, the request has a hash and the
    hash is the same when we excrypt the data with that hosts api key

    Arguments:
    app -- instance of the application
    """
    consumers = app.config.get('API_CONSUMERS')
    host = request.host

    try:
        api_key = next(d['api_key'] for d in consumers if d['host'] == host)
    except StopIteration:
        raise UnknownHostException(
            app.logger, 'Authentication failed: Unknown Host (' + host + ')')

    if not request.headers.get('hash'):
        raise MissingHashException(
            app.logger, 'Authentication failed: Missing Hash (' + host + ')')

    hash = calculate_hash(request.method, api_key)

    if hash != request.headers.get('hash'):
        raise HashMismatchException(
            app.logger, 'Authentication failed: Hash Mismatch (' + host + ')')


    return True


def calculate_hash(method, api_key):
    """
    Calculates the hash using either the url or the request content,
    plus the hosts api key

    Arguments:
    method  -- request method
    api_key -- api key for this host
    """
    if request.method == 'GET':
        data_to_hash = request.base_url + '?' + request.query_string
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data_to_hash = request.data

    data_to_hash += api_key
    return hashlib.sha1(data_to_hash).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building on @Drewverlee's answer, I would consider renaming `BaseException` to `APIException`, or something of the like.

Also, I don't think passing app as an argument is best practice, I would recommend using the function as a decorator on your endpoints instead:

```
# Your imports
from application import app # Or whatever your non-relative reference is

def is_authenticated(func):
    def func_wrapper():
        # Your code here without the original def call
    return func_wrapper
```

You can then use this on each endpoint, adding the `@is_authenticated` decorator, to ensure the app is properly authenticated.

Answer (score 6):

Exception itself actually inherits from a class called BaseException so:

```
class BaseException(Exception):
```

Seems backwards.